# How to get href content

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, html-parsing, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract link from href.`<a class="p_l" href="" id="0" target="_blank">`
This is what is visible in page view source but when i inspect using firebug, href will contain `http://home.website.com/preview/preview?uname=3eadsf132sdas`. I tried using htmlagilitypack but href is returning null. How to extract the link in href.

Comment: That's because an empty `href` means "whatever the current URL is". Agility pack cannot know where you got your HTML from.

Comment: Is it possible to extract the link. How to get the link in href.

Comment: @Maddy to reiterate what the first commenter says, there is nothing to extract. Firebug is showing you what the *web browser* knows. HTML Agility Pack only knows what the *HTML source* knows. The browser knows where it loaded the HTML from, Html Agility Pack does not. Instead of looking at firebug, look at "view source". That is what HAP actually sees.

Comment: Thank you @jamietre. I got it. My problem is , when a user clicks on that `href` tag, it will be redirected to another page. I want to extract that link. When view source is only not showing the link then how to extract it.

Comment: Maddy, you can't. That information *is not available* in the source. What the browsers is showing users *is not coming from the HTML source.* It is probably being populated with javascript or is just missing as the first commenter said (and represents the base page url).

Answer (score 1):

If you have not tried this way than please try it this way

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;

        htmlDoc.Load(filePath);

 foreach(HtmlNode link in htmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    if(link != null)
    {
      if(link["href"] != null)
      {
       HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
       var url = att.Value;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you HatSoft, but DocumentElement is giving error and if i use DocumentNode then it's giving error saying that we can not use node as an array.

Comment: @Maddy what's the error thrown by DocumentElement, I use this all the time

Answer (score 1):

You could try something different, like getting the html content using the WebRequest class (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) how).

If the href doesn't contain any link it could mean that it is being populated using Javascript or some other programming language to add the dynamic content. If you have access to the scripts then you might have a small chance to get the links, but don't think so.